# How can I extract all text between different sets of strings in Swift?

Tags: swift

For example I want to extract all text that sits between any one of these string combinations:

```
[["<p>", "</p>"], ["<h4>", "</h4>"]]
```

This string:

```
"<h4>Food</h4> random stuff <p>Is good</p> more random stuff <p>When hot</p>"
```

should give me this result:

```
["<h4>Food</h4>", "<p>Is good</p>", "<p>When hot</p>"]
```

Note: It is important that the string combination used to extract the text remain in the final array as shown above.

Comment: What is your goal with this? You can display HTML formatted text on UI elements using built in methods. Are you sure you really need to get the HTML formatted parts of your string?

Comment: are you trying to convert HTML to string? or are you actually need to extract the HTML tags as they appear. What you are saying can be done but it will be annoying as compared to just displaying HTML.

Comment: I've considered simply displaying HTML but these pieces of text are going to be applied to labels with custom attributes. I'm not sure how to manipulate the HTML to make the label look the way I want.

Comment: Do you want to keep the HMTL formatting __and add__ some further formatting to it? Or do you want to drop the HTML formatting completely and just add the extra formatting? In any case, you should start your research along the lines of `NSAttributedString`s.

Comment: I would highly recommend against trying to parse yourself. There be dragons. Use an html parsing library do it for you.